# Cookie not set at local development Express REST API + react SPA

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, axios, setcookie

I have googled for a while now and still no luck. I am running a REST api using nodeJS + express at localhost:3000. On the same computer I am running the frontend on 127.0.0.1:3001. From my backend API I am receiving the set-cookie header. But it is not being treated as a cookie by my browser. Hence, Application -> Cookies -> http://127.0.0.1:3001 is empty. I have tried chrome, safari and firefox. In chrome I have tried turning off these flags:

- SameSite by default cookies
- Enable removing SameSite Cookies without
- SameSite must be secure

The suggestion I tried from google was:

- use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
- disable flags in chrome
- use firefox instead
- include credentials in axios request: withCredentials: true
- To no set Domain under cookie options

When I deploy to production everything works as intended. There seem to be many people with this issue but none of the solutions I have found has worked.

Response header:

[image]

Comment: If cookie is issued by localhost: 3000 then you won't find it listed under localhost: 3001. It's perfectly normal and expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that under domain I was including the port. Simple using domain: "localhost" did the trick. At first I had domain: "localhost:3001"